# jQuery if body hasClass then sidemenu toggleClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve is toggling the sidemenu on click anywhere in the body except inside sidemenu div itself. I currently can toggle the sidemenu from its toggle link (comment out line 13-14 in js fiddle) but not by clicking anywhere on body. This is the concerned code:

```
$('body').bind('click', function (e) {
var opened = $('body').hasClass('sidemenu-open');
if (opened === true) {
    $('.sidemenu').removeClass('is-visible');
    $('body').removeClass('sidemenu-open');
}
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gp8z9q29/1/)

I know I can add a wrapper for the content but I don't have much flexibility in the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. First, when you click on the link, the click is bubbling out to the body. So the menu toggles open, then it toggles closed again, so nothing happens. Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent that.

Second, when the side menu is closed, `<body>` is just the one line containing the link. If you want to be able to click anywhere in the window, use `$(document)` rather than `$('body')`.

```
$(function () {
    $('.sidemenu-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.sidemenu').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $('body.sidemenu-enabled').toggleClass('sidemenu-open');
        $('.sidemenu').toggleClass('sidemenu-open');
    });
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var opened = $('body').hasClass('sidemenu-open');
    if (opened === true) {
        $('.sidemenu').removeClass('is-visible');
        $('body').removeClass('sidemenu-open');
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gp8z9q29/3/)

Comment: Some useful checks are missing for IE older version :)

if (!event) event = window.event;

Comment: I assume jQuery does that internally when it's constructing the argument list to the handler. That's one of the benefits of using a library like jQuery or Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Your click on the side menu is propagating down to the body and activating that handler as well - `preventDefault` isn't what you're after, you need to return `false` as well. Try this click handler instead.

```
$(function () {
    $('.sidemenu-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        $('.sidemenu').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $('body.sidemenu-enabled').toggleClass('sidemenu-open');
        $('.sidemenu').toggleClass('sidemenu-open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need event.preventDefault when using 'return false' as in jQuery event handler 'return false' takes care of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the target element in click event by which you can have further conditions.

```
    $('body').click(function(evt){    
           if(evt.target.id == "your_sidemenu_id"){
            //do nothing    
           }
           else{
           //do the toggle here as this will be implemented whenever any element is clicked other than your sidemenu
           }

});
```

Comment: IE (older versions) doesn't support the target property, they use srcElement instead.

Change:

if (evt.target.id != 'show_calender')

to:

if ((evt.target || evt.srcElement).id != 'show_calender')

You may also need to add this to the beginning of your function:

if (!evt) evt= window.event